# How to build iPhone and iPad targets with the same filename in Xcode 4?

Tags: ios, ipad, xcode4, targets

Our company created an iOS app that has an iPhone version and an iPad version. The app is called "SaveMyPlace". We wanted to call the iPad version "SaveMyPlaceHD", but that name was too long, and got truncated on the springboard screen.

We ended up calling both versions of the app the same thing, "SaveMyPlace." This worked find in Xcode 3.x. You just select your first target, build it, do what you need with it, then select the second target, build **that**, and you're good to go.

In XCode 4, the build system wants to build both targets at the same time. I have 2 targets set up, with the appropriate source files nibs, graphics, etc, set up for each target. However, Xcode builds both targets in the same directory, and the iPhone version ends up overwriting the iPad version of the the app.

How do I set up Xcode to build 2 separate targets with the same filename, and save the resulting .app files into separate directories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just beacuse your app's name is different doesn't mean that you can't just display the same name on springboard.

In your info plist

`CFBundleIdentifier` defines the unique id for your app.

`CFBundleName` defines the name displayed on springboard.